# What server side solution did Google Wave used?

Tags: comet, live, node.js, server-push

I wonder what server side solution Google used for Google Wave.

I have heard that they used Node.js for this. Is that true?

Or did they use other non-open source solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wave uses GWT](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWavePoweredByGWT.html) which suggests that the server side was written in Java. The code that's been open-sourced so far seems to corroborate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run Wave gadgets using websockets, e.g using Wave-Node. See https://github.com/scottbw/wave-node